# Как сделать команду видимой только для юзера,который её вводил на python?

Tags: python, discord.py

Мне интересно,как сделать такую команду,код пишу,используя коги.

Comment: Отправить ответ в ЛС. Сообщения в каналах видны всем у кого есть разрешение на это.

Comment: Хорошо,спасибо,так же можно использовать параметр hidden = True, и тогда сообщение будет эфемерным)